# document.getElementById("id") in onchange parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an ERP program where i needto write data *to and from* a database.
Here i would like to send data with an input field, therefore i call a specific javascript function on an onchange event.
I would like to add the value of another element with the onchange parameter like this

```
onchange="myFunction(document.getElementById("myId"))"
```

I already tried this but it does not work:

```
onchange="myFunction(document.getElementById(\"myId\"))"
```

How do i do this?

Comment: you can use single quotes as well

Comment: @Thomas http://stackoverflow.com/a/34825625/4763793 please see this

Comment: you can use `onchange="myFunction(document.getElementById(\"myId\"))"` but only thing is that the function should be defined before it is being called

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
onchange="myFunction(document.getElementById('myId'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `onchange="myFunction(document.getElementById('myId'))"` you're getting the element. If you want to use the value you have to use `onchange="myFunction(document.getElementById('myId').value)"`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
onchange="myFunction(document.getElementById('myId'))";
```

Comment: i think one more thing should be added here is that the function myFunction should be defined before the use of onchange property

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get element in such way. It can be done right inside your function:
*html part:*

```
onchange="myFunction()"
```

*js part:*

```
function myFunction(){
    var target_id = document.getElementById("myId").value;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
onchange="myFunction(this.id)"
```

**Example**

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  alert(id)
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this.id)">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
    <option value="BMW">BMW
      <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>
```

In JavaScript, the thing called [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp), is the object that "owns" the current code.The value of this, when used in a function, is the object that "owns" the function.

Answer (score 0):

this.value will do. use it like

```
onchange=myFun(this.value) or onchange="myFun(this.value)"
```

both should work